# java, collect data from one JTable, using event handler change display of other JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionlistener

Since the program is too large I'll just paste the important parts of code. Here's the problem:
I have two `JTable`s. First one collects data from DB and displays the list of all invoices stored in DB. The purpose of the second table is when you click on one row from the table, event handler needs to collect integer from column ID. Using this ID the second table will then display all the contest of that invoice (all the products stored in it).

First and second table work perfectly. The problem is that I have no idea how can I collect certain data (I basically just need ID column) from a selected row and then through a method I already made update the second `JTable` with new info. Here's my code if it helps:

(PS: once I learn how to do that, will the list on the left change every time by default when I select different row, or do I need to use validate/revalidate methods?)

```
public JPanel tabInvoices() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("", "20 [grow, fill] 10 [grow, fill] 20", "20 [] 10 [] 20"));

        /** Labels and buttons **/
        JLabel labelInv = new JLabel("List of all invoices");
        JLabel labelPro = new JLabel("List of all products in this invoice");

        /** TABLE: Invoices **/
        String[] tableInvTitle = new String[] {"ID", "Date"};
        String[][] tableInvData = null;
        DefaultTableModel model1 = new DefaultTableModel(tableInvData, tableInvTitle);
        JTable tableInv = null;
        /** Disable editing of the cell **/
        tableInv = new JTable(model1){
            public boolean isCellEditable(int r, int c) {
                return false;
            }
        };
        /** Load the invoices from DB **/
        List<Invoice> listInv = is.getAllInvoices();
        for (int i = 0; i < listInv.size(); i++) {
            model1.insertRow(i, new Object[] {
                    listInv.get(i).getID(),
                    listInv.get(i).getDate()
            });
        }

        /** TABLE: Invoice Info **/
        String[] tableInfTitle = new String[] {"ID", "Name", "Type", "Price", "Quantity"};
        String[][] tableInfData = null;
        DefaultTableModel model2 = new DefaultTableModel(tableInfData, tableInfTitle);
        JTable tableInf = null;
        /** Disable editing of the cell **/
        tableInf = new JTable(model2){
            public boolean isCellEditable(int r, int c) {
                return false;
            }
        };
        /** Load the products from DB belonging to this invoice **/
        List<Product> listPro = is.getInvoiceInfo(1); // Here's where I need the ID fetched from selected row. For now default is 1.
        for (int i = 0; i < listPro.size(); i++) {
            model2.insertRow(i, new Object[] {
                    listPro.get(i).getID(),
                    listPro.get(i).getName(),
                    listPro.get(i).getType(),
                    listPro.get(i).getPrice(),
                    listPro.get(i).getQuantity()
            });
        }


        /** Scroll Panes **/
        JScrollPane scrollInv = new JScrollPane(tableInv);
        JScrollPane scrollPro = new JScrollPane(tableInf);

        panel.add(labelInv);
        panel.add(labelPro, "wrap");
        panel.add(scrollInv);
        panel.add(scrollPro);

        return panel;
    }
```

For now, the right table only displays content of the first invoice:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the help of following code you can get the value of selected clicked cell, so you just have to click on `ID` cell value (the Invoicee ID whose Products you want to see in second table) and with the help of following event handler you will get the value and then you can get data based on that ID and set to second table. (In the code below, `table` is the object of your first table)

(Off-course you will have to apply some validation too, to check that the selected (and clicked) cell is `ID` not the `DATE`)

```
    table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            int row = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
            int col = table.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());

            Object selectedObj = table.getValueAt(row, col);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Selected ID is " + selectedObj);
        }
    });
```